# incrementing records with same date

Tags: mysql, sql

i have to autonumer fields with same date an i honestly have no idea how to :(

```
(what i have)
ID|| DATE || PID 
1 || 2014 01 01 || 1
2 || 2014 01 01 || 2
3 || 2014 01 02 || 3
4 || 2014 01 02 || 4
(what i need)
ID|| DATE || PID
1 || 2014 01 01 || 1
2 || 2014 01 01 || 2
3 || 2014 01 02 || 1
4 || 2014 01 02 || 2
```

Comment: Please post the question properly otherwise their is no use of it as nobody will be able to understand.

Comment: sorry for bad post (my first here so far).
i already have dates in database (quite alot of them) and i have to index same dates something like :
foreach(var row in table){
if(row.date==previousRowDate) PID=++i;
else PID=i=0;
previousRowDate=row.date;
}
trivial in c# but impossible or me in sql

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new record and If ID is auto increment:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(DATE, PID)
VALUES ( [YOUR_DATE], (SELECT MAX(PID) from table_name where DATE=[YOUR_DATE]) + 1)
```

Change `[YOUR_DATE]` with the date you want to insert